# cabal could not find module snap.internal.http.server.exception

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-snap-framework

I have a Haskell desktop application that uses Snap. This application has been building for years now and is an everyday part of our fielded solution. I upgraded to a new development machine some months ago, running Windows 10 with version 7.10.3 of the GHC and 1.22.3.0 of the cabal library with 1.22.4.0 of cabal-install. I have installed version 0.9.8.0 of snap-core and version 0.9.5.1 of snap-server.

When I try and build my application in this environment, it get the following error:

```
Could not find module `Snap.Internal.Http.Server.Exception'
Perhaps you meant
  Snap.Internal.Http.Server.Backend
  Snap.Internal.Http.Server.Config
  Snap.Internal.Http.Server.Date
```

I cannot find this module in Hackage. Did something change in Snap since I last built this code? Please, any advice will be appreciated.

Dave

P.S. Here are links to the output of the ghc-pkg list command and to the cabal file for this project.

http://zelda.designacourse.com/dave/ghc-pkg_list.txt
http://zelda.designacourse.com/dave/PreviewWrapper.cabal

Comment: can you give us some more information about the running application - say a `ghc-pkg list` or a `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list`, another option is to use stack (http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html)

Comment: also in the older application which cabal/ghc versions do you use

Comment: The last time that this built successfully I was running a 2014 Haskell platform. I no longer have the exact version, as I had to uninstall it before I could install the new version.

Comment: do you have time to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103332/discussion-between-epsilonhalbe-and-dacdave).

Comment: Please, in the future, don't paste such long output samples (or indeed any information relevant to answer) in comments. Edit it into your question instead.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, Can we pick a time for a chat. I will make myself available on your schedule.

Comment: we can talk feb 15 - 22:00 gmt+1 ?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, As I understand you are in Austria (GMT+1) and I am in EST (GMT-5). If this is correct, your 22:00 (10 PM) is my 16:00 (4 PM). I will be here at that time. Thank you for this offer.

Comment: I tried adding the LANGUAGE pragma Haskell98 to see if this might be something that changed in recent Haskell. I think the last time I built this program with the 2014 Haskell platform we were already beyond the Haskell 98 changes, but I tried it anyway. No change.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of, and gratitude to, epsilonhalbe we found a solution to this problem. I still do not know why the import of Snap.Internal.Http.Server.Exception started to throw an error from the compiler. However, removing that import and adding a type declaration to the variable now allows the code to build without error. i.e. catch ((_ :: IOException) -> return True).